# Apache Hive Installation on pseudo distributed or multi node cluster environment

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, hdfs, hadoop2

I have installed hadoop on multi node environment in my PC as below

## 1: 4 virtual box instances loaded with ubuntu(14.04)

## 2: 1-master node , 2-slave node and remaining vm instance works as client

**Note: All 4 VM'S are running in my PC itself**

I was able to complete apace-2.6 hadoop setup successfully on the above mentioned setup .Now I want to install hive in order to do some data summarization, query, and analysis .

But I am not sure how I have to proceed further. I have few queries mentioned below :

Q1: Do I need to install/setup Apache Hive(0.14) on all nodes(master/name-node and slave/data-node)? or is it only on master node?

Q2: what is the mode should be used to deal with the meta-store is it local mode or remote mode ?

Q3: In case if I want to use mysql for hive meta-store,should I install it on master/name node itself or do I need to use separate client machine for this?

please can some one also share me if there are any steps to be followed to configure metastore? in multi node/pseudo distributed environment.

BR,
San

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the required Hive services (HiveServer2, Metastore, WebHCat) only once. In your lab scenario, you would probably put them on the master. The client can then run Beeline (the HiveServer2 client.)

If you configure the Metastore as Local, Hive will use a local Derby database. Again, for your lab setup, this is probably just what you need/want.

In a production scenario, you would

- set up a dedicated server for supporting services that should not fight for resources with the namenode process(es)
- and use a dedicated database server for your Metastore database, which will be remote.

Comment: Regarding your answer, would like to consult. I'm creating cluster using lxc. Could you describe cluster architecture for production? I have ready Hadoop cluster (1 namenode, 2 slaves). or provide link how properly configure hive multinode cluster on production? Thanks.